# Subscribing to a service as the length of the *ngFor array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have a div with ngFor and a button inside the div where it calls a sat popover event

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders">
  <button mat-icon-button [satPopoverAnchorFor]="popover_address" (click)="openAddressView(order)">
   <mat-icon matTooltip="Edit Address" class="icon">edit_location</mat-icon>
  </button> 
</div>

<sat-popover (closed)="closeAddressView()" #popover_address horizontalAlign="end" hasBackdrop verticalAlign="center">
    <app-order-address></app-order-address>
</sat-popover>
```

in the component calling a service

```
openAddressView(order: any){
    this.popover_address.open();
    this.ordersService.getAdddresses(order);
}
```

and subscribing to the service as follows.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, 
ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmMap, AgmMarker, AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { OrdersService } from '../../../Services/orders- 
service/orders.service';
import { SatPopover } from '@ncstate/sat-popover';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-address',
  templateUrl: './order-address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-address.component.scss']
})
export class OrderAddressComponent implements OnDestroy {
  title: string = 'address';
  lat: number = 33.8950888;
  lng: number = 35.5186542;
  zoom: number = 8;
  height: string = '500px';
  addresses: Array<any>;
  selectedAddressId: number;
  @ViewChild(AgmMap) private myMap: any;
  @ViewChild('mapContainer') mapContainer: any;
  @ViewChild(AgmMarker) AddressPin: any;

 constructor(private OrdersService: OrdersService, private cdr: 
ChangeDetectorRef) {

  this.OrdersService.loadClientAddresses.subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.addresses = response.addresses;
    this.selectedAddressId = response.selected_address.id;
    this.recenterMap(response.selected_address.lat, 
    response.selected_address.lon);
    console.log(response); // PRINTS 10 TIMES
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  });

}
```

All works well except when I click on the button to open the popover.
console.log prints as the length of the orders object. ex( if I have 10 orders it will print 10 times)

I want it to only subscribe to the service when it is clicked.

Comment: does it call `console.log` respectivly the code in the subscription 10 times?
is the method `loadClientAddresses` just a http call (with HttpClient)?

Comment: You're actually subscribing to the service method 10 times, so the expected behaviour is to call the code inside the subscription 10 times (including console.log). A better solution is to subscribe to the service once on the parent component, and pass the data to the child component through property binding.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you have 10 instances of the app-order-address. The component construct one app-order-address for each popup even if the pop up is not triggered (?)... (test with a 'console.log' at the top of 'constructor' method)

If you have 10 constructors calls , you have 10 times subscribe. So when you click on one button, it triggers all the 10 subscribe.

You should move some logic in the parent component (maybe look also for "sharedReplay" in rxjs)